# How to structure JMeter tests to re-use samplers/controllers in multiple test plans?

Tags: jmeter

Yesterday, I started to write my first test cases with **JMeter**. Everything worked fine, but my test plan is growing and becomes messy. My problem is that I have a complicated login process with multiple HTTP calls which I need to do before each of my tests. The best way to re-use this login functionality I found so far is this:

[image]

I have a thread group (called *Do the SAML Login*) which is `disabled`. It contains two controllers which encapsulate the login and logout. Under that I have multiple thread groups for the actual tests (the screenshot only shows the first one). Each thread group starts and ends with an `Once Only Controller` to do the login and logout respectively. Between them are my actual test calls.

**My problem is the following:** I can execute my tests in a loop and all calls between my `Once Only Controllers` are executed multiple times while the login and logout is executed only once (cool!). But when I run with  multiple threads, the login/logout is also done multiple times in threads.

How can I prevent this? I think I'm looking for some setup-up and tear-down method for my thread groups, but I don't know how to do it with JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest moving your login and logout logic into [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) and [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) correspondingly

You can use [Test Fragments](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments) in combination with the [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) to re-use your login/logout login in multiple test plans.